# Assigning structural zeros in ergm (and gergm)

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph, graph-theory

I'm using ergm and gergm packages to fit a model to a dataset of 10 networks. In PNET I can assign a structural zeros file which dictates which ties are being simulated. Does anyone know how to do this in either ergm or gergm? Can't find anything online about this.

Comment: This is possible, but the solutions are not straightforward. There's a lot of discussion of this on the dragnet users group (e.g., [here](http://mailman13.u.washington.edu/pipermail/statnet_help/2012/001214.html).

Comment: Best solution IMHO is to use a tergm with no time dependencies. See the discussion [here](http://mailman13.u.washington.edu/pipermail/statnet_help/2015/002083.html).

Comment: presumably this isn't possible for a gergm then?

Comment: The first link _might_ work--throwing all the networks into a joint adjacency matrix and the using node attributes to prohibit btw network ties. But it's a hacky solution at best.

Comment: OK great! Thanks a lot

Comment: Another thought: you could fit an ergm/gergm separately for each network and then use a meta-analysis to compare the coefficients (for example [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2747768/) and [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/757b/52120ad5508571dd01ad6059b21c6c274521.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
?ergm.constraints
```

Assuming, each node could belong to a single network, having unique network id as an attribute should work, i.e.

```
m1 <- ergm(
   formula = ...,
   constraints = ~ blockdiag("network_id")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Brennan Antone for the info